# Redirecting traffic going to a single endpoint to a function in Azure Cloud Services (classic)

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I've got a web api at api.mydomain.com running on Azure cloud services (classic).

I want a certain endpoint, say api.mydomain.com/end/point, to instead trigger an Azure function, and all the other traffic continue going to the app on api.mydomain.com.

How do I do that with minimal overhead? This is an extremely highly trafficked endpoint so I'd like to optimize it to be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is an Azure Application Gateway since it supports URL path routing which is what you need to do. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/

That might be too much overhead but it would meet your need.

Another option to consider is using the IIS Application Request Routing module on your cloud service.  This [support thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dbe9f003-04e8-420c-b0fc-609cdf30d913/application-request-routing-with-windows-azure) and this [blog post](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/how-to-install-iis-application-request-routing-in-windows-azure/) talk about that approach.  (Warning both are a bit dated)